# High availability in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How can I implement High Availability in SQL Server 2005/2008 Standard.
Some people Recommended me to use third party tools such as double take.
What do you think.

Comment: I voted for Jason's answer below, and jl gives some good background. Can you describe more fully what you're doing now and what you'd like it to look like when it's all done?

Comment: Thanks, well we have two SQL servers machines and we want to add mirroring and high availability to them. and a web server who we like to connect it to the SQL servers through connection pooling technique.
in the bottom of line we have a site and we want it to have access to sql servers. if one falls down the other keeps working.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason is correct.  Keep in mind that the cluster shares a quorum drive.  A clear definition of "High Availablity" is necessary since the clustering is for the front end server on not the (presumably) external storage.

Double-take might be satisfactory for a disaster recovery scenario where the intent is to fail-over an entire database server to a separate physical site.  If memory serves me, you will have to map your current server to the secondary server so that Double-take knows where to place the files it copies.   A secondary server laid out exactly like your primary server makes this easier.  I believe there can also be some latency issues depending on the distance between the primary and secondary servers.  That being said Double-take will help you set up a test of the product to see how it performs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very useful even the one from jason, a vote up from me.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 Standard edition supports 2 node clustering out of the box, as well as synchronous database mirroring.  You can also use third party tools to do this.